# Javascript check if elements in array are same type and return true/false

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay so I have this array:

```
var data = [1, 2, {a: 1}, [43], '3'];
```

And I need to check and see if the following elements are in this array:

```
 1  -> should return true
 43 -> should return false
 3  -> should return false
'3' -> should return true
```

This is what I have:

```
    function has(list, element) {
    console.log(list); //gives me data = [1, 2, {a: 1}, [43], '3'];
    console.log(element); //gives me first 1, then 43, then 3, then '3'


    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var decision = true;
      switch (decision) {
        case (list[i] == element):
          console.log("Yes in array.");
          decision = true;
          break;
        case (element !== list[i]):
          console.log("Not in array.");
          decision = false;
          break;
      }
    }

    return decision;

  }
```

This is what I get in the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkZqT.jpg

The main problem is how do I check if the type (element and array) match ? I tried using === and it didn't work.

Comment: What about using `includes` function?

Comment: Why don't you just use `===` instead of `==` so that it doesn't coerce types?

Comment: @Barmar I did try with === and still got the same problem. In the end I fixed  it with includes thanks to you and Zooly :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `includes` function from `Array.prototype`.

```js
var data = [1, 2, {a: 1}, [43], '3'];

console.log(data.includes(1)); // true
console.log(data.includes(43)); // false
console.log(data.includes(3)); // false
console.log(data.includes('3')); // true
```

Comment: This worked, thanks Zooly and @Barmar. Don't know how I forgot about this.

Comment: @IkePr You're welcome! As said Vignesh, it won't work for object

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf()`:

```
var data = [1, 2, {a: 1}, [43], '3'];

function has(list, element) {
    return list.indexOf(element) > -1 ? true : false; 
}

console.log(has(data,3)); //false
console.log(has(data,'3')); //true
```